# Visual studio bad autocomplete

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, visual-studio-2013

I'm using VS2013, I have situation in function for example:

```
void fun(const A &a)
{
 //here I write
}
```

When I start typing 'a', '.', then instead of '.' i get '->' :-/ Do you know how can I fix it ? Turn of intelisense not help.

A is a struct.

Comment: I can't repro the problem from this description.  If you can make this happen consistently, consider filing a bug on Microsoft Connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using visual assist by whole tomato. You can disable that in its options.

Comment: It can be this, I useing Assit ;-)